# supabase storage not downloading correctly

Tags: typescript, react-native, supabase

I am trying to download images that I have uploaded to my bucket as an `ArrayBuffer` as that is what is recommended by the docs when using react native. When downloading the file it returns a `Blob`. When stringifying the returned blob data shows something like this:

`{"size":1650788,"offset":0,"blobId":"f3833299-2b40-426a-8d78-489b9d5c1894","__collector":{}}`

Using chat gpt it told me that this is just metadata about the image, and is probably why I cannot use the blob.arrayBuffer() function that the Blob has. I receive no errors downloading the file and it is downloading from the correct bucket and folder. I only receive the following error when trying to convert the Blob to an ArrayBuffer.

`Error converting data to ArrayBuffer:, [TypeError: undefined is not a function]`

Here is my code:

```
const result = await supabase.storage
        .from("images")
        .download(`${user_id}/${image_id}`);

      if (result.error) {
        console.error("Error downloading image:", error);
      } else if (result.data) {
        try {
          console.log("data:", JSON.stringify(result.data));
          // console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data));
          const buffer = await result.data.arrayBuffer();
          console.log("Image ArrayBuffer:", buffer);
          // You can use the buffer to display or manipulate the image data here
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error converting data to ArrayBuffer:", error);
        }
      } else {
        console.error("No data or error returned");
      }
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this as the images are viewable on the supabase dashboard, and the only way I could manage to upload them was using an ArrayBuffer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found documentation on supabase storage and react native downloads: https://supabase.com/blog/react-native-storage#file-upload-to-supabase-storage

I had to use a FileReader to parse the blob object:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
        .from("images")
        .download(`${post.userId}/${post.imageId}`);

      if (error) {
        console.error("Error downloading image:", error);
      } else if (data) {
        try {
          return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            const fr = new FileReader();
            fr.readAsDataURL(data);
            fr.onload = function () {
              resolve(fr.result as string);
            };
            fr.onerror = function () {
              reject("error");
            };
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error reading image:", error);
        }
      } else {
        console.error("No data or error returned");
      }
```